# city/address search autocomplete in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I'm currently working on a web-project where we need to be able to get accurate addresses for activities that the users create. So my idea here was to implement a autocomplete city and address search field without using a map.(much like the one facebook has when creating arrangements) As the user type, he gets suggestions... This would then be used to let user find activities based on distance from a location specified in the same manner. (This probably means I need coordinates for the addresses/cities)

I'm just wondering if there's any free frameworks out there that will let me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to use that information go actually get distances, (not *just* the autocomplete,) what you're probably looking for is a "Geocoding" API. That is something which takes addresses and turns them into coordinates. Probably the most famous one out there is the Google Maps one. There's some detailed information on the JavaScript version here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html

There's an jquery component which hooks into that API, which would probably make things even easier for you (disclaimer: I haven't actually used this library, I just found it). You can get it from here:
http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will look into the google maps api with that jquery component. Looks promising...

Answer (score 1):

If google maps isn't a good choice for you, check out the autocomplete service from Addrexx - http://www.addrexx.com.  It will autocomplete addresses from most countries in the world and is inexpensive or free in some case.  There are straight web services or a complete solution available.  It will even autocomplete apartments and suites.

I believe that it will provide the functionality that you need.  I know the service very well since I work for Addrexx.

Answer (score 0):

Which country are you targeting?

If you’re interested in finding **New Zealand postal addresses** with reserve geocoding lookups, you can use the [Address Search API](https://www.addy.co.nz/address-finder-and-postcode-api) for address autocomplete suggestions.

Once you have a unique address id or the latitude and longitude (X and Y) coordinates, you can use the [Geocoding Address API](https://www.addy.co.nz/address-reverse-geocoding-api) to find nearby addresses with “as the crow flies” distances in kilometres.

You can also narrow down the “near me” locations based on a bounding box / polygon area using the [Bound Box Address API](https://www.addy.co.nz/bounding-box-area-address-api).

You can use the [Google’s Simple Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) to plot the information on a map using JavaScript.